# What does the "e" flag mean in fopen

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I saw a code snippet using `fopen(file_name, "r+e")`. What does the `e` flag mean in fopen? I couldn't find any information from the linux man page.

Answer (score 7):

On a [GNU webpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html) I found that the `e` means that the "file descriptor will be closed if you use any of the exec… functions".

Answer (score 5):

It's documented in the man page on my system (release 3.54 of the Linux man-pages project).

> **e** (since glibc 2.7)
>    Open the file with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag.  See `open(2)` for more information.  This flag is ignored for `fdopen()`.

Scroll down; it's under "Glibc notes".  This is a non-standard extension.

An online copy of the man page is [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).